# Replace random substring in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, replace, substring

I am trying to replace random substring with another within a string. This is my code

```
function replaceRandomSubstring(str, substr, repl) {
  var amount = str.match(substr)
  var newstr = str;
  if (amount.length != -1) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * amount.length)
    var i = 0;
    do {
      if (i == index) newstr = newstr.replace(substr, repl)
      else newstr = newstr.replace(substr, "placeholder")
      i++;
    }
    while (i < index)
    newstr = newstr.split("placeholder").join(substr)
  }
  return newstr;
}
```

What's happening is that it replaces the very first substring not random one

Comment: Can you show an example of the values you're passing to the function.

Comment: @Teemu replaceRandomSubstring(teststring, "test", "replacement")

and teststring contains: "test, test, test, test, test"

Comment: OK, and you want to replace a single `substr` only, not a random amount of the occurrences?

Comment: a single substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `amount` doesn't return all matches of the substrings. It returns the first match.

Use [`String.prototype.matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) instead:

```
function replaceRandomSubstring(str, substr, repl) {
  const amount = [...str.matchAll(substr)]; // collect all substring matches into one array

  if (amount.length !== -1) {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * amount.length);

    let i = 0;

    do {
      if (i === index) str = str.replace(substr, repl);
      else str = str.replace(substr, 'placeholder');
      i++;
    } while (i <= index);

    str = str.split('placeholder').join(substr);
  }
  return str;
}
```